# Push val of input to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I'm pushing multiple inputs to a array but this is a lot of repeating code, how can I improve this?

```
 var tickets = [];
    $('.js-ticket').each(function(){
      var ticket = [];
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_naam\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_aantal\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_prijs\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_begin_datum\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_begin_tijd\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_eind_datum\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_eind_tijd\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_aanal_max\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      ticket.push($("input[name='ticket_aanal_min\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      tickets.push(ticket);
    });
  historyVar['tickets'] = tickets;
  });
```

The Html is reader simple just 9 input fields and i'm running this part on a click of a button

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're pushing into the array. could you add a full code snippet e.g the html bit and how the array is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var tickets = [];
var names = [
    'ticket_naam', 'ticket_aantal', 'ticket_prijs', 'ticket_begin_datum',
    'ticket_begin_tijd', 'ticket_eind_datum', 'ticket_eind_tijd',
    'ticket_aanal_max', 'ticket_aanal_min'
];

$('.js-ticket').each(function() {
    var $ticket = $(this);
    var ticket = $.map(names, function(name) {
        return $ticket.find('input[name="' + name + '\\[\\]"]').val();
    })
    tickets.push(ticket);
});
```

The one thing I want to point out is I'm searching within each `.js-ticket` for the inputs, instead of searching globally each time like your function was. I have to imagine this is what you were intending to do in the first place, otherwise the outer `each` doesn't make much sense.